# DataTables Editor: How to use objects instead of arrays?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I'm wondering how I can use objects instead of arrays in a DataTables Editor project. The author of the plugin [recommends using objects instead of arrays](http://datatables.net/manual/data#Objects), but I can't find a detailed write-up as to how to configure the plugin to use objects. Below is the code I've used thus far with arrays.

JS:

```
    var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
        ajax:  "../stack/plugins/datatables/php/table.qpidvulh_to-do_list.php",
        table: "#qpidvulh_to-do_list",
        fields: [
            {
                label: "Item",
                name: "item",
                type: "textarea"
            },
            {
                def: "(none)",
                label: "Office",
                name: "office",
                type: "select",
                ipOpts: [
                    {
                        label: "(none)",
                        value: "(none)"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Alaina",
                        value: "Alaina"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Felicita",
                        value: "Felicita"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Lee",
                        value: "Lee"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Luciana",
                        value: "Luciana"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Rachel",
                        value: "Rachel"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                def: "Office",
                label: "Expeditor",
                name: "expeditor",
                type: "select",
                ipOpts: [
                    {
                        label: "Office",
                        value: "Office"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Carlos",
                        value: "Carlos"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Danny",
                        value: "Danny"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Steve",
                        value: "Steve"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: "Deadline",
                name: "deadline",
                type: "date",
                dateFormat: "mm\/dd\/y",
                dateImage: "https://www.dcturano.com/stack/images/calendar.png"
            }
        ]
    });

    $('#qpidvulh_to-do_list').dataTable({
        ajax: "../stack/plugins/datatables/php/table.qpidvulh_to-do_list.php",
        autoWidth: "false",
        dom: "<'H'lfr>t<'F'ip>",
        jQueryUI: "true",
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        stateSave: "true",
        type: "post",
        columns: [
            {
                data: "item",
                width: "54%"
            },
            {
                data: "office",
                width: "10%"
            },
            {
                className: "p_hide",
                data: "expeditor",
                width: "10%"
            },
            {
                className: "p_hide",
                data: "deadline",
                width: "9%"
            },
            {
                className: "p_hide",
                data: "created",
                width: "9%"
            },
            {
                className: "center p_hide",
                data: null,
                defaultContent: "<a href=''class='editor_edit'>Edit</a> | <a href='' class='editor_remove'>Delete</a>",
                orderable: false,
                width: "8%"
            }
        ]
    })
```

Server script:

```
<?php

/*
 * Editor server script for DB table qpidvulh_to-do_list
 * Automatically generated by http://editor.datatables.net/generator
 */

// DataTables PHP library
include( "lib/DataTables.php" );

// Alias Editor classes so they are easy to use
use
    DataTables\Editor,
    DataTables\Editor\Field,
    DataTables\Editor\Format,
    DataTables\Editor\Join,
    DataTables\Editor\Validate;


// Build our Editor instance and process the data coming from _POST
Editor::inst( $db, 'qpidvulh_to-do_list' )
    ->fields(
        Field::inst( 'item' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::minLen_required', 5 ),
        Field::inst( 'office' ),
        Field::inst( 'expeditor' ),
        Field::inst( 'deadline' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::dateFormat', 'm/d/y' )
            ->getFormatter( 'Format::date_sql_to_format', 'm/d/y' )
            ->setFormatter( 'Format::date_format_to_sql', 'm/d/y' ),
        Field::inst( 'created' )
            ->set( isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'create' ? true : false )
            ->getFormatter( 'Format::date_sql_to_format', 'm/d/y' )
    )
    ->process( $_POST )
    ->json();
```

Comment: you can transform it yourself, or use the format documented on the main datatables server-side page.